# Replace Java Util Logging with Log4j2 specific to web application on tomcat

Tags: log4j2, tomcat9, java.util.logging

I have a java application deployed on tomcat 9+. I am aware how to change the default tomcat logging to instead use log4j2.
I have done this by following this https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html.
I wanted to know rather than changing the default tomcat logging to use log4j2 is it possible to use log4j2 only for my war file without changing the code. My application has used JUL for logging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

These days almost any logging configuration is possible.

Tomcat uses a special JUL `LogManager` (cf. [`ClassLoaderLogManager`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/ClassLoaderLogManager.html)) that allows to specify a different JUL configuration in every application.

To redirect all JUL logs from your application to Log4j2 the easiest way is to pass through SLF4j. To do this:

1. Add [`jul-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32) and [`slf4j-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32) to your project,
2. Add a `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` configuration file that redirects everything to the [`SLF4JBridgeHandler`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html):

   ```
   handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
   .handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
   ```
3. Add the Log4j 2.x dependencies to your project: [`log4j-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1), [`log4j-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1) and [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1) and the SLF4j binding [`log4j-slf4j-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.14.1).
4. Configure Log4j 2.x as you wish.

**Warning:** There is a performance penalty in this solution (cf. [SLF4j documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j)).

Comment: Than you for your response. I have few queries. The jars you mentioned does that need to be placed inside WEB-INF/lib. Secondly configure log4j2, should I place the log4j2.xml inside the WEB-INF/classes or all the configurations of lof4j2.xml must be done in logging.properties

Comment: All jars I mention should be bundled with the application (inside `WEB-INF/lib`). You also need a `log4j.xml` file, although you can configure the levels of the loggers also in `logging.properties` and the less verbose level from both files will be effective.

Comment: Tried the steps. Added jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar, log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.1.jar, log4j-web-2.14.1.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar, log4j-api-2.14.1.jar and log4j-core-2.14.1.jar to WEB-INF/lib and log4.xml and logging.properties to WEB-INF/classes. Logging manager is set to org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager. All logs are getting logged to console out and not to the files mentioned in log4j.xml. Initially I was getting this error 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. I renamed log4j2.xml to log4j.xml and this warning dont come but still logs are being logged to console out

Comment: Since you had to add `log4j.xml`, you must have Log4j 1.2 somewhere in your dependencies. Probably the logs sent to SLF4J end up there instead of Log4j 2.x.